# jquery вытащить id из ссылки

Tags: jquery

```
<a href="/katalog-to/Audi/A1/A1-8X1-2010---CAXA/4681-disk-tormoznoj-zadnij.html"class="incart-js icons i_cart"></a>
```

Как можно выдернуть id в моем случаи 4681?

Comment: если все ссылки будут похожего типа, то можешь попробовать найти последний слеш '/' и скопировать всё до первого дефиса после него

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const linkHref = $('.incart-js').attr('href'),
  id = linkHref.match(/\/(\d+)-/)[1];
  
console.log(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/katalog-to/Audi/A1/A1-8X1-2010---CAXA/4681-disk-tormoznoj-zadnij.html"class="incart-js icons i_cart"></a>
```

Comment: Спасибо,  как можно теперь переменную id вставить сюда (вместо 4681)
$('.mainmenubg').prepend('<a class="new_link" href="/search/?find=4681" alt="Аналог" title="Аналог">Аналог</a> '); ?

Comment: @gbrgbr, `$('.mainmenubg').prepend('<a class="new_link" href="/search/?find=' + id + '" alt="Аналог" title="Аналог">Аналог</a> ');`

Comment: что я делаю не првильно ? ошибка Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

if ($('.subdiv-katalog-to .table_main').text()) {

    $('.mainmenubg a').hide();
    var linkHref = $('.mainmenubg div.incart-js a').attr('href'),id = linkHref.match(/\/(\d+)-/)[1];
    $('.mainmenubg').prepend('<a class="new_link" href="/search/?find='+ id +'" alt="Аналог" title="Аналог">Аналог</a> ');
}

Comment: @gbrgbr, Смотрите что у вас в `linkHref`, должна быть строка.